# Getting following error while migrating Spring boot version from 2.1.6 to Spring boot 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Getting following error while migrating my project from Spring boot version 2.1.6 to 2.4

**No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element**

Code Snippet where error is coming

```
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/**/test/**")
    }
}
```

I know Spring boot disable AntPathMatcher in version 2.4 , so I tried this option as well

Spring.mvc.pathpattern.matching-strategy= ant_path_matcher

but even this is not working

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: General advice: do not try to make 3 major version jumps in one go. Migrate to 2.2, then 2.3, then 2.4. That way, you will pinpoint the exact version which has an incompatibility. Spring publish a migration guide for every version, and you can check it to see what problems you might have, and it will provide advice on how to fix it. They **don't** publish a migration guide for every permutation of possible version jumps.

Comment: `/**/test/**` is already a bit dubious and that is the reason why it isn't allowed anymore in newer Spring versions. (`**` means multiple levels so basically, any URL containing /test/ will match regardless of the levels of nesting.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for suggestion , I have tried for that . till 2.3 it is working fine but when I am migrated to 2.4 it is giving error , in Spring boot 2.4 release note this is mentioned            Add a configuration property to opt-in for the new PathPatternParser in lieu of AntPathMatcher to parse and match request mapping path patterns                                                                                                                     https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes

Comment: @M.Deinum i just override my real URI with test because I cant share real uri here

Comment: Please read my comment. It isn't about the test but about the fact that there are multiple unbound wildcards, which isn't permitted anymore (afaik).

Comment: @M.Deinum ohh , yes you are right , but this is existing code and I don't know impact if I will remove **?

Comment: Any workaround to fix the issue, none of the suggested solutions is working

Answer (score 17):

With the newest version 1.5.12 of springdoc-openapi-ui the problem is solved for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 14):

the reason:
The error is a path wildcard problem. The search found that the path wildcard has changed after the spring upgrade to 5.3. The official explanation is "In Spring MVC, the path was previously analyzed by AntPathMatcher, but it was changed to use PathPatternParser introduced in WebFlux from Spring 5.3.0.".

solve:
The specific solution is to change `/**/*.css` to `/*/*.css`. Multiple files may be involved in the project, and they must be changed.

Comment: Application coming with the change but routing is not happening

Answer (score 5):

Set this in your application.properties. Either that or just edit the patterns.

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher

Answer (score 5):

Please note that in newer versions of Spring the correct property is `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy` (and not `spring.mvc.pathpattern.matching-strategy`)

More info:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy

Relevant issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28791

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. The correct property is "spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy"

Answer (score 2):

It seems using CAPS is working:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```