# Spring Security Configuration match URL with dots (.)

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to block URL other URL's expect

```
http://localhost:8081/odata/v4/com.sap.di.remoteHandler.RemoteHandlerServices/Handle
```

But, since the URL has dots (`.`) I am facing the below error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
```

```java
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    try {

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests( url ->  url
                .requestMatchers("/**/Handle").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().denyAll())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> oauth
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                    .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter())
                )
            )
            .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer
                .contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicyConfig -> contentSecurityPolicyConfig
                    .policyDirectives(CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY)
                )
            );
            return http.build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Authentication is failed");
    }
}
```

What will be right pattern so that i can match the URL?

Comment: The problem is that you specify something after the two asterix ** which is not allowed, not that URL has dots. Use ant-path matcher. Also this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118420/getting-following-error-while-migrating-spring-boot-version-from-2-1-6-to-spring

Comment: i had already tried and it doesn't work .. the problem is that its considering . as pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create an `AntPathRequestMatcher` which does the job:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    try {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(url ->  url
                 .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/**/*RemoteHandlerServices/Handle")).authenticated()
                 .anyRequest().denyAll()
             )
             .sessionManagement(session -> session
                 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
             )
             .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> oauth
                 .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                     .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter())
                 )
             )
             .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer
                 .contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicyConfig -> contentSecurityPolicyConfig
                     .policyDirectives(CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY)
                )
             );

            return http.build();

    } catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("Authentication is failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with your URL having dots(.) in its path name, but in Spring SecurityFilterChain, while matching URLs, the `**` is taken to be as a wildcard, depicting that 'anything that follows this'. For example, assume

```
http
     .authorizeHttpRequests( url ->  url
     .requestMatchers("odata/v4/**").authenticated()
     .anyRequest().denyAll())
```

means that any URL starting with `odata/v4/` and whatever might follow after it is going to be matched by that matcher, and will be processed as mentioned. Therefore, if you are going to manually specify anything after `**` that does not have any precise meaning. Which is exactly why you are seeing this error.

```
org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
```

If you want to not get this error, remove the `/Handle` after your code to make it look like this

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    try{

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests( url ->  url
                        .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().denyAll())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(
                        oauth -> oauth.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter()))
                ).headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer
                        .contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicyConfig -> contentSecurityPolicyConfig
                                .policyDirectives(CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY)))
        ;
        return http.build();

} catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("Authentication is failed");
    }
}
```

this will work, but this will make EVERY request being made to your server to be matched by that matcher, which in turn wants the request to be authenticated, since you are matching every request of the base URL and anything that follows it. If that is what you want, then you have your answer, else you can add the pattern you want to match exactly as it is to the requestMatcher, to have specific requests to be authenticated.

If you want to only allow `http://localhost:8081/odata/v4/com.sap.di.remoteHandler.RemoteHandlerServices/Handle` then you should have

```
.requestMatchers("odata/v4/com.sap.di.remoteHandler.RemoteHandlerServices/Handle").authenticated().anyRequest().denyAll())
```

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: Adding the complete URL works fine

Comment: Yes, glad to hear it. Hope you learned stuff from the answer.

Answer (score -1):

instead of .requestMatchers("/**/Handle").

Try with below,

`.regexMatchers("*.*/Handle$")`

Let me know if it is not working

Comment: Using spring-security 6.1.5, where all other matchers are deprecated and removed

Comment: In Spring Security 5.x and later versions, including Spring Security 6.1.5, the antMatchers() and regexMatchers() method is still a valid and commonly used way to define URL patterns. Both methods is not deprecated, and you can continue to use it for more complex URL pattern matching. Can you just try once, if not working ill try to provide alternate solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).